# Infinite parallel stream map reduce pipeline with time limit in Java

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-stream, java-threads

I'm trying to implement this concurrent strategy in Java.
I really don't care if I'm using streams or executors, the important thing here is efficiency.

I want to run as many simulations as possible, in parallel, within a given time deadline. A single simulation runs faster than the timeout. New simulations should be submitted whenever there's capacity in the underlying thread pool.

```
+----------------+         +--------------+           +------------+
|                |  param  |              | Solution  |            |
| SimCoordinator +-------->+  Simulation  +----+----->+ reduce(min)|
|                |         |              |    |      |            |
+-------+--------+         +--------------+    |      +------------+
        ^                                      |
        +--------------------------------------+
```

Classes look something like:

```
class SimCoordinator {
    double getParam(); //changes every time
    double putSolution(Solution s);
}

class Simulation {
    Solution run(double param); // takes a while to compute
}
```

A coordinator supplies a parameter to a task.

The task is then run and a solution is obtained.

The solution must be fed back to the coordinator, which will change how the parameter is generated.

Each solution has a cost; I want to save the solution with the minimum cost, and do this while the simulations are run, not after the deadline.

Simulation.run() is a long operation hence it should be run concurrently with other simulations. Let's say I have a threadpool (or however parallelstreams are working) of N threads. Initially simcoordinator feeds all threads with simulations, and as simulations finish, it creates new ones.

What's the best way to approach this kind of problem?

Comment: You are describing a causal loop and it’s not clear, where parallelism should come into play when each simulation needs a parameter based on the previous simulation.

Comment: @Holger, sorry for not being clear.
Simulation.run() is a long operation hence it should be run concurrently with other simulations. Let's say I have a threadpool (or however parallelstreams are working) of N threads. Initially simcoordinator feeds all threads with simulations, and as simulations finish, it creates new ones.

I'll update my question

Comment: Just create a `Thread Pool` with `n` Threads where `n` is the number of cpu cores you have...

Comment: So a single simulation is supposed to run significantly faster than the timeout, so you might submit more when there’s capacity?

Comment: @Holger exactly. If there was no timeout, the simulations would be submitted forever.

Answer (score 0):

So essentially what you have is

- the simulation - a `Function<Double, Double>`
- a calculation of a new parameter depending on the old one and its result, ie `BiFunction<Double, Double, Double>`
- an evaluation that records the lowest parameter/score set, ie `Consumer<Double, Double>`.
- a timer that runs out, preventing new simulations from starting.

So all in all you could have something like

```
class SimulationDriver {
    private ExecutorService service;
    AtomicBoolean finished = new AtomicBoolean();
    private ScheduledExecutorService timer = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    private Function<Double, Double> simulation;
    private BiFunction<Double, Double, Double> calculateNewParameter;

    private Map<Double, Double> results = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    private SimulationDriver(Function<Double, Double> sim,
                             BiFunction<Double, Double, Double> newParam) {
        simulation = sim;
        calculateNewParameter = newParam;
    }

    public void run(int timeout, Runnable callback, Double... params) {
        if (service != null) throw new InvalidStateException("already running");

        // initial simulations, one in each thread
        service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(params.length);
        for (Double d : params) {
            submitForSimulation(d);
        }
        // after timeout: set finished to prevent new simulations and notify caller
        timer.schedule(() -> { 
            finished.set(true);
            service.shutdown();
            callback.run(); // tell outside world we're finished
        }, timeout, ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    void submitForSimulation(Double d) {
        if (!finished.get()) { // don't start new simulations after time ran out
            CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> simulation.apply(d), service);
            result.thenAccept(r -> results.put(d, r)); // store param/result in map
            // calculate next parameter and run simulation with that
            result.thenAccept(r -> calculateNewParameter.apply(d, r))
                  .thenAccept(this::submitForSimulation);
        }
    }
}
```